# Disabling automatic scrolling of UITableView when editing UITextField inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I'm using custom `UITableViewCell`s inside my `UITableView`. Each of these `UITableViewCell`s is pretty high and contains a `UITextField` at the top.

When a user taps the `UITextField` in order to edit it, a keyboard appears and the `UITableView` scrolls automatically so that the cell is at the top of the screen.

The problem is that this scrolls the `UITableView` to the bottom of the `UITableViewCell`, not the top. When the `UITableViewCell` is high and edited the `UITextField` is at the top so you can't see the `UITextField`. I know how to scroll the `UITableView` programmatically, but I just don't know how to disable this automatic scrolling so that I can scroll the `UITableView` on my own. How can I do this?

Comment: You figure this out? Running into the same problem.

Comment: @SteveBaughman have you found solution?

Comment: nope :( i actually stopped using table view for because of this and some other reasons ... :/

Comment: It's definitely an issue with UITableViewController's automatic behaviors.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The autoscroll-behavior is located in the `UITableViewController` functionality.

To disable the automatic scrolling I found two ways:

1. Use instead of the `UITableViewController` simply a `UIViewController` - set the datasource and delegate on your own.
2. Override the `viewWillAppear` method and don't call `[super viewWillAppear: animated]`

With both solution you disable not only the Autoscroll, but also some other nice but not essential features, that are described in the overview of Apple´s class reference:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller

Comment: I had the same problem and solution 2 worked. I've tested this in iOS 5.0.0 and upwards and it holds so far (current release is 6.1.2). I can't vouch for it in 4 but hey, it's 2013, so we can probably say 5.0 is the lowest supported os right now.

Comment: Problem with this is that the insets are not adapted to accommodate the keyboard, at least not in iOS 7.0.6.  This means that more code will be needed to do this by hand: catching keyboard notifications, ...  Ugly.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know about this till today.. I was having problems with TPKeyboardAvoiding.. Thanks!!

Comment: Point no2 works on 9.1. Good answer @Dominic. Thanks

Comment: Option 2 is so weird. I suddenly had the automatic scrolling disable, and I didn't have super view will appear thingy XDXDXD. How could that change everything LOL

Comment: I wouldn't ever override viewWillAppear: without calling super. UITableViewController subclasses UIViewController, and Apple "requires" all UIViewController subclasses to call super. From the [UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear): "If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation."

Comment: i am using `UITableViewController` if i don't use `supper.viewWillApper()` function then my footer is not coming on the top of `keyBoard` what should i do for that `Means i want to stop auto scrolling and want footer view on the top of keyboard while editing`

Answer (score 8):

Define properties for your `UITableViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL scrollDisabled;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lastContentOffsetY;
```

Before you call `becomeFirstResponder`:

```
// Save the table view's y content offset 
lastContentOffsetY = tableViewController.tableView.contentOffset.y;
// Enable scrollDisabled
scrollDisabled = YES;
```

Add the following code to your table view controller:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.scrollDisabled) {
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, lastContentOffsetY)];
    }
    ...
}
```

After you call `resignFirstResponder`, set `scrollDisabled = NO`.

Comment: This isn't a scrollview problem, is a tableViewController class. The correct answer was the override viewWilAppear

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)unregisterForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    double delayInSeconds = 0.3;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    });
}
```

Then implement this UIScrollViewDelegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (! self.tableView.scrollEnabled)
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}
```

!!! But be warned, that if the user taps in a location in the UITextField that will be covered by the Keyboard, then it won't scroll.

**From my point of view, the best thing to do is to make sure that all the cells from top to then one with the UITextField included, will be visible when then Keyboard will show.**

Comment: -scrollViewDidScroll: does indeed get called when automatic scrolling happens, this here is the best solution

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to subclass `UITableView` and then override `setContentOffset(_ contentOffset: CGPoint, animated: Bool)` and not to call `super.setContentOffset(_ contentOffset: CGPoint, animated: Bool)`. In this method is where the view controller is doing the automatic scroll.

```
override func setContentOffset(_ contentOffset: CGPoint, animated: Bool)
{
    //Do nothing
}
```

Comment: This was the correct answer for me for a UITableView with UITextView in the cells.

Answer (score 3):

You could disable the automatic content inset adjustment like so:

```
tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Comment: This won't work as the keyboard will obscure the cells beneath it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was not so much that it scrolled but that it took the text view being edited off the screen.

So instead of preventing the scrolling, I just rescroll the tableview to where I want when the editing is triggered, like this:

```
public func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {            
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    tableViewController.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(self.indexPath!, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, animated: true)
  }
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, overriding -viewWillAppear: doesn't work for me in iOS 8.

Here is my solution (as in UITableViewController implementation):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.tableView name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.tableView name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Since the auto-scrolling behaviour is invoked by UIKeyboard's show/hide notifications, so just NOT observe them.

Comment: is this still working for you? Can't get it working in iOS 11 / Xcode 9

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to set "scrollsToTop" - tableview's property to NO. By default it is YES.

Comment: tried it yet, but it didn't work...scrollToTop doesn't handle this... thanks for answer anyway!

Answer (score -6):

You can try doing the following:

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

This should disable the scrollview in the tableview.

Comment: This does not prevent the automatic scrolling the UITableViewController does when tapping on a text field within a UITableViewCell