# How to stop scroll UITableView when textField on it become first responder?

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard

I added a `textfield` to tableview's cell and when textfield become first responder then tableView scrolls up. Even dow I set `self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false`. How can I prevent this phenomenon?

Comment: Override the `viewWillAppear` method and don't call `[super viewWillAppear: animated]` More you can found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637089/disabling-automatic-scrolling-of-uitableview-when-editing-uitextfield-inside-uit