# The clicked UITextFiled is moved out of the interface

Tags: ios

Load cell in UICollectionViewController, cell is XIB hybrid development, there are UITextFiled.
When you click UITextFiled, the keyboard pops up, the entire View moves up, the clicked UITextFiled is moved out of the interface.
Seek help：
There is no way to turn off the keyboard pop-up View automatically move up. Or who knows what's wrong with it?

[image]

---

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

}
I found a solution: to implement this method and not call [super viewWillAppear:animated] can be solved.

Comment: it seems that you have a keyboard notification firing up wherein it moves the current view up. maybe check for that notification and work from there

Comment: I haven't dealt with it

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember when you use TableViewController or CollectionViewController they get this behaviour automatically.
You have to disable the autoscroll or you can add keyboard notification observer and re scroll the tableView back to where it was

[Disabling automatic scrolling of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637089/disabling-automatic-scrolling-of-uitableview-when-editing-uitextfield-inside-uit)